# Plotting a parametric function with three input variables

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a 2D parametric function of the form:
$$
f_x(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) = \cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3)
$$
$$
f_y(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) = \sin(\theta_1)+\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)+\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3)
$$

where the ranges for the input variables are: $ \theta_1 \in [-\pi,\pi]$ and $ \theta_2 \in [-\pi,\pi]$ and $ \theta_3 \in [\frac{-\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}]$

I tried to use `ParametricPlot`, but it takes only two input variables.

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it should be a union of these things:

```
Table[ParametricPlot[With[{c = c},
  {Cos[a] + Cos[a + b] + Cos[a + b + c],
   Sin[a] + Sin[a + b] + Sin[a + b + c]}],
  {a, -Pi, Pi}, {b, -Pi, Pi}], {c, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/24}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Show[%, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Using smaller step sizes in the `Table` command, it becomes pretty evident you get an annulus contained in the disk of radius 3.  A little analysis shows that the annulus has outer radius 3 and inner radius $2\sqrt{2}-3 \approx -0.171573$.

Comment: I can't see the relevance for using a With Statement.

Comment: @hieron The `With` statement is certainly not necessary but makes it super simple to extract individual plots. You can use `With[{c=Pi/2},___]`, for example to look at that particular image. It arose because I did exactly that when trying to figure out what was going on mathematically. Clearly, this would be particularly nice, if there were more `c`s in the expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot [
    {Cos[a] + Cos[a + b] + Cos[a + b + c], 
     Sin[a] + Sin[a + b] + Sin[a + b + c]}, 
    {a, -Pi, Pi}, {b, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Yellow], 
  {c, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/24}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Effect of `c` in `Manipulate` is to change diameter of smallest circle of tangency for circle traversing disk. Slow step by step change of c works better to update plot. You can see effects by Manipulate slider e.g., swapping between c and a produces eccentric circles etc...